# SQL: choose a column name dynamically based on its value from the table

Tags: php, sql

I a have a table name(weight) in database

| id | 1000 | 500 | 300 | 100 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 | 120 | 140 | 180 | 200 |

for 1000 (1kg)time required is 60

for 500 (.5kg)time required is 120 and so on

based on this weight data should be fetched from the table

If the entered weight by the user is 700 it should fetch the data of 500 which is the less than 700 and return the value 120

so my code must be like

```
    SELECT (column name)<700 FROM Weight WHERE id=1
```

Thanks:)

Comment: I would suggest changing your database design as currently if you want to alter the ranges you would have to change both the database design as well as any code using this table.

Answer (score 2):

It will be much easy if you rearrange your data like:

```
id, condition, value
1,  1000       60
1,  500        120
1,  300        140
```

and the query would be like this:

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE id=1 AND condition < 700 ORDER BY condition DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: While this is the correct approach, the column should not be called `case`, as this is a reserved word in SQL.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm agree with you

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not efficient to get your desired results.

Update your table:weight with the below one.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `weight` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `weight` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `weight` (`id`, `weight`, `time`) VALUES
(1, 100, 60),
(2, 500, 120),
(3, 300, 140),
(4, 100, 180),
(5, 1, 200);
ALTER TABLE `weight`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `weight`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
COMMIT;
```

Add use the following query to get your desired results.

```
SELECT time FROM weight WHERE weight<=700 ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case .. when` in `select` clause as follows:

```
Select case when your_value >= 1000 then column_1000
            when your_value >= 500 then column_500
            when your_value >= 300 then column_300
            when your_value >= 100 then column_100
             Else column_1 
       End as res_
  From your_table t
```